# Unexpected bash directory listing with *

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I have a issue with case sensitive directory listing in my bash. for example

```
   $ touch  nohupa nohuPb
   $ ls nohup*
   nohupa  nohuPb
```

However I do expect it only list nohupa not nohuPb. because nohuPb has capital P. 
I don't know what variable in my .bashrc set that * works ignore case.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's [`nocaseglob`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) that causes that.

> *nocaseglob*
>  If set, bash matches filenames in a case-insensitive
>   fashion when performing pathname expansion (see Pathname Expansion
>   above).

testing

```
$ touch fooab fooAb
$ ls
fooAb fooab
$ shopt -s nocaseglob
$ ls fooa*
fooAb fooab
$ shopt -u nocaseglob
$ ls fooa*
fooab
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your shell has the `nocaseglob` set. You can unset it by using a `shell built-in` called `shopt`. Use `-s` option to `enable` it and `-u` option to `disable` it.

For more reference you can visit [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#nocaseglob).